# How to fix JsonProperty issue in springboot model class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok, spring-annotations, snakecasing

I am trying to change the attribute name to snake_case for the response in a model class. The Jsonproperty works fine with DB entity class, but not with the model class which does not have any DB entity mapped.
sample code which is not working.

SubtestResult.java -- Modelclass

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

public class SubtestResult {
  @JsonProperty("expected_value") @Getter @Setter private String expectedValue;
  @JsonProperty("actual_value") @Getter @Setter private List<String> actualValue;
}
```

Assertion.java

```
public class assertion {

private SubtestResult calculate(string actualValue){ 
    SubtestResult subtestResult = new SubtestResult();
    subtestResult.setActualValue(actualValue);
    subtestResult.setExpectedValue("true");
}
```

Actual result

```
{ 
"expectedValue": true
"actualValue": false
}
```

Expected :

```
{ 
"expected_value": true
"actual_value": false
}
```

Note: There is no DTO entity for this. this entire model object gets stored as a string.

Comment: Can you go into more detail as to how you are using your `SubtestResult` model class. And post your expected vs. actual JSON?

Comment: @drumonii updated with more details

Comment: Which Lombok version are you using?

Comment: lombokVersion = '4.1.6' @JanRieke

Comment: Your JsonPropertys look good. Can you share how you are generating the JSON? Include jackson imports in your samples. Do you have any global serialization config? Or perhaps using a json view?

Comment: This issue resolved by adding the @SerializedName annotation for model class